# Ajax post successful (shown in browser) but no data in $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm relatively a beginner in PHP/Javascript/HTML.
Here's what my page looks like:
   I have several forms each with a single dropdown.
   Then, I have one button (in the code, it's located outside the form) to submit all of the said forms.
   Here's my button and its function.

```
<input type="button" name="order_button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Place Order">
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
      <?php
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "secret", "judal");
        $all_cards_q = "SELECT * from card";
        $result = $conn->query($all_cards_q);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        { ?>
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Proj-HOME.php",
            data: $('<?php echo $row["cardForSub"]; ?>').serialize(),
            success: function() {
              alert("WOOO SUCCESS!");
            }
          });
          //return false;
          //document.getElementById('<?php echo $row["cardForSub"]; ?>').submit();
        <?php
        }
        ?>
  } 
  </script>
```

I'm getting a "200 OK" status code in chrome, but $_POST contains nothing (I'm using print_r after posting).
I've been stuck for two days trying to find an answer but couldn't quite see one that exactly fits my situation. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: ** Here is my form code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">                
          <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          ?>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt=""> -->
              <img src="pics/cards/<?php echo $row["cardName"] ?>.jpg" alt="" border=3 height=150 width=100> 
              <div class="caption">
                  <font color=#3333FF size=5 face="Century Gothic">
                  <p><?php echo $row["cardName"] ?></p>
                  </font>
                  <p></p>
                  <h4><b>Php <?php echo $row["cardPrice"] ?>.00</b></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="ratings">
                <p class="pull-right"> <?php echo rand(10,100) ?> reviews</p>
                <p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                </p>
                <font color=#000000><p>Quantity: </p></font>
              </div>
              <form action="javascript:true;" name="<?php echo $row["cardForSub"]; ?>" id="<?php echo $row["cardForSub"]; ?>">
                <select class="form-control" name="<?php echo $row["cardNickname"]; ?>" id="<?php echo $row["cardNickname"]; ?>">               
                <?php
                  $counter = 0;
                  while($counter <= $row["stock"]) {
                ?>
                    <option><?php echo $counter ?></option>

                <?php
                    $counter++;
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php    
              }
            }
            else echo "No cards in database.";
          ?>     
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: where are you trying to read $_POST? on proj-home.php?

Comment: `$(document.getElementById('<?php echo $row["cardForSub"]; ?>')) ` ? Why is it not `$('#<?php echo $row["cardForSub"]; ?>');`

Comment: remove that forward slash from the `url`. Change `url: "Proj-HOME.php/",` to `url: "Proj-HOME.php",`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I have tried that before and it still didn't work. Reason I put it is I saw some get problems without the terminating slash.

Comment: @ahervin I have tried what you wrote but it gave no change. Thanks though, yours looks to have made more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Issue 1 :`

The Target Page `Proj-HOME.php/` It means the file named as `index.php` or `index.html` inside `Proj-HOME.php`

I guess that you are trying to post to the page `Proj-HOME.php/` . If so remove the `/` after the file name i.e., Have like this `Proj-HOME.php` alone

`Note 1 :`

Try to print some variable in the `Proj-HOME.php` and try to see in the ajax success event so that you can make sure that you're pointing on correct page.

`Note 2 :`

Check whether you included jquery library to make this events works, also try to these code in page source so that you can make sure that these code is getting rendered in page.

Comment: I have already removed the trailing '/' as mentioned in my other comments. I'm editing the post now.

And I've also checked that I've included the jquery library but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Paul In network tab,does the request carries the parameter that you have ?

Comment: It says status code 200 with a green dot and okay in each post method. It iterates 6 times, as I would like it to. And in the preview tab (where it shows a preview of Proj-HOME.php) it gets shows in the print_r. But when I go to the Proj-HOME.php itself $_POST contains nothing

Comment: Does the network tab, carries the parameters that you include ?

Comment: What do you mean by parameters here? Sorry I'm a beginner.

But I can see "Request Method: POST"

Then below there's "Form Data" and below it is the value BlueEyes=0 (6 times, with different data for each post)

Comment: Parameters are the form values .. If you go to Network Tab and click on the Request, it should be left side , near to the header in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I profess to no jQuery skills but to me it looks like there is something amiss with the function ~ where you call `$(document.getElementById()).serialise()` - I don't think you need to `document.getElementById` in there. Also, it would be neater to separate the html, javascript and php a little... and, like @Raj pointed out ~ the url should more likely begin with a slash than end with one.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form/ajax</title>
        <script>
          <?php
                $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'judal');
                $all_cards_q = 'SELECT * from card';
                $result = $conn->query( $all_cards_q );
                while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ){
                    $cfs_id=$row->cardForSub;
                }
                $conn->close();

                echo "var cfs_id='{$cfs_id}';";
          ?>
          function myFunction() {
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Proj-HOME.php',
                data: $( cfs_id ).serialize(),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                success: function() {
                    alert('WOOO SUCCESS!');
                }
              });
          } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <input type='button' name='order_button' onclick='myFunction()' value='Place Order'>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried removing the getElementById but it still doesn't work :(